# Python - Finding word frequencies of list of words in text file

Tags: python, text, frequency

I am trying to speed up my project to count word frequencies. I have 360+ text files, and I need to get the total number of words and the number of times each word from another list of words appears. I know how to do this with a single text file.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\PDF-to-txt")
>>> filename="1976.03.txt"
>>> textfile=open(filename,"r")
>>> inputString=textfile.read()
>>> word_list=re.split('\s+',file(filename).read().lower())
>>> print 'Words in text:', len(word_list)
#spits out number of words in the textfile
>>> word_list.count('inflation')
#spits out number of times 'inflation' occurs in the textfile
>>>word_list.count('jobs')
>>>word_list.count('output')
```

Its too tedious to get the frequencies of 'inflation', 'jobs', 'output' individual. Can I put these words into a list and find the frequency of all the words in the list at the same time? Basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520876/counting-the-frequency-of-specific-words-in-text-file) with Python.

Example: Instead of this:

```
>>> word_list.count('inflation')
3
>>> word_list.count('jobs')
5
>>> word_list.count('output')
1
```

I want to do this (I know this isn't real code, this is what I'm asking for help on):

```
>>> list1='inflation', 'jobs', 'output'
>>>word_list.count(list1)
'inflation', 'jobs', 'output'
3, 5, 1
```

My list of words is going to have 10-20 terms, so I need to be able to just point Python toward a list of words to get the counts of. It would also be nice if the output was able to be copy+paste into an excel spreadsheet with the words as columns and frequencies as rows

Example:

```
inflation, jobs, output
3, 5, 1
```

And finally, can anyone help automate this for all of the textfiles? I figure I just point Python toward the folder and it can do the above word counting from the new list for each of the 360+ text files. Seems easy enough, but I'm a bit stuck. Any help?

An output like this would be fantastic:
    Filename1
    inflation, jobs, output
    3, 5, 1

```
Filename2
inflation, jobs, output
7, 2, 4

Filename3
inflation, jobs, output
9, 3, 5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[collections.Counter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) has this covered if I understand your problem.

The example from the docs would seem to match your problem.

```
# Tally occurrences of words in a list
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
print cnt


# Find the ten most common words in Hamlet
import re
words = re.findall('\w+', open('hamlet.txt').read().lower())
Counter(words).most_common(10)
```

From the example above you should be able to do:

```
import re
import collections
words = re.findall('\w+', open('1976.03.txt').read().lower())
print collections.Counter(words)
```

**EDIT** naive approach to show one way.

```
wanted = "fish chips steak"
cnt = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('1976.03.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
```

Comment: I've been fooling with Counter for several hours now, and still can't get it.

Comment: The example above is going to give me tally of all of the unique words in my textfile (over 3000 unique words in my case). I only need the tally for 10-20 specific words in the textfile.

Comment: I think that will work for the list, great thank you! I stared at that Counter page for hours haha

Comment: if it was useful either upvote the answer or tick accepted so that others know it worked.

Comment: @sotapme I'm trying to do similar thing, but I cannot use the library collections. Any ideas on how it can be done without it?

Answer (score 5):

One possible implementation (using Counter)...

Instead of printing the output, I think it would be simpler to write to a csv file and import that into Excel. Look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html and replace `print_summary`.

```
import os
from collections import Counter
import glob

def word_frequency(fileobj, words):
    """Build a Counter of specified words in fileobj"""
    # initialise the counter to 0 for each word
    ct = Counter(dict((w, 0) for w in words))
    file_words = (word for line in fileobj for word in line.split())
    filtered_words = (word for word in file_words if word in words)
    return Counter(filtered_words)


def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    """For each .txt file in a dir, count the specified words"""
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            ct = word_frequency(f, words)
            if action:
                action(filepath, ct)


def print_summary(filepath, ct):
    words = sorted(ct.keys())
    counts = [str(ct[k]) for k in words]
    print('{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n\n'.format(
        filepath,
        ', '.join(words),
        ', '.join(counts)))


words = set(['inflation', 'jobs', 'output'])
count_words_in_dir('./', words, action=print_summary)
```

Comment: Which variables above do I need to replace? Where do I need to put in my specific directory?

Comment: Rob, Can you please tell me where in the above code I should put the directory folder I'm working in and the list of words I am interested in? I'm not sure what I have to put into the 3 functions you defined.

Comment: The path to the directory you want to process is the first argument to the function `count_words_in_dir()`. See the last line of the code. Your set of target words is the second argument to the same function. See the penultimate line.

Answer (score 0):

A simple functional code to count word frequencies in a text file:

```
{
import string

def process_file(filename):
hist = dict()
f = open(filename,'rb')
for line in f:
    process_line(line,hist)
return hist

def process_line(line,hist):

line = line.replace('-','.')

for word in line.split():
    word = word.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
    word.lower()

    hist[word] = hist.get(word,0)+1

hist = process_file(filename)
print hist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, os, sys, codecs, fnmatch
import decimal
import zipfile
import glob
import csv

path= 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sentiment2020\\POSITIVE'

files=[]
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if'.txt' in  file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r,file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
    file1= codecs.open(f,'r','utf8',errors='ignore')
    content=file1.read()

words=content.split()
for x in words:
    print (x)

dicts=[]
if __name__=="__main__":  
    str =words
    str2 = [] 
    for i in str:              
        if i not in str2: 
              str2.append(i)  
    for i in range(0, len(str2)):
        a= {str2[i]:str.count(str2[i])}
        dicts.append(a)
for i in dicts:        
    print(dicts)



#  for i in range(len(files)):
  #    with codecs.open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sentiment2020\\NEGETIVE1\\sad1%s.txt' % i, 'w',"utf8") as filehandle:
  #         filehandle.write('%s\n' % dicts)
```