# Using a Text file to count certain words in PYTHON

Tags: python

I am in need of a lot of help. I am trying to use a text file to count only certain words from the text. I have been searching for hours to try and find help, but cant seem to find any.

NEEDS TO BE incase senitive 
The words i need to use are:
great, good, perfect, nice, fantastic, loved, love, happy, enjoyed, fabulous

Comment: Sorry but we cannot help you unless you show what you have tried. Look for tutorials on how to read from text file. How to iterate through the data you read and how to compare the iterations to your list of words (there is a specific method to enforce case-sensitivity, and increment your counters if there is a match. Good luck

Comment: Possibly helpful or related [Python - Finding word frequencies of list of words in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921436/python-finding-word-frequencies-of-list-of-words-in-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like "re.findall" or "re.finditer" expressions to search the words, then loop through whole file.

```
    list = []
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        words = f.read()
        list.append(re.findall(r"great", words))
```

Then you can count the words through len function.
The code might need minor modifications according to the requirements.
Go through the regular expressions page for more info on it.

You can even use str.count().

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` offers many options for counting words

```
from collections import Counter

with open('alice.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

c = Counter(content.split())

print(c['you'])

lst = ['me', 'them', 'us']

for i in lst:
    print(f'{i}: {c[i]}')

for word, count in c.most_common(5):
    print(word + ':', count)
```

> ```
> 301
> me: 46
> them: 49
> us: 10
> the: 1664
> and: 780
> to: 773
> a: 662
> of: 596
> ```