# Print the amount of times a word is in a pdf - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have a problem when using pypdf when looking for the amount of times a specific word is in a pdf file.

In my code, it founds the amount of times a word is, but only one time a page. So the maximum is the amount of pages. The word "the" should result in around 700, but only shows 30 (the amount of page is 30).

```
import PyPDF3
import re
def read_pdf(file,string):
    fils = file.split(".")
    print(fils[1])
    word = string
    if fils[1] == "pdf":
        pdfFileObj = open(file,"rb")
    # open the pdf file
        object = PyPDF3.PdfFileReader(file)
    # get number of pages
        NumPages = object.getNumPages()

    # define keyterms
        counter = 0
    # extract text and do the search
        for i in range(NumPages):
            PageObj = object.getPage(i)
            print("page " + str(i))
            Text = PageObj.extractText()
            #print(Text)
            if word in Text:
                print("The word is on this page")
                counter += 1
        print(word, "exists", counter, "times in the file")
```

Can you guys see what i have done wrong and help me with it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You read the text of one page into `Text` and check if `word in Text` - so if the word is `the` and the `Text = "the the the the the the the the the "` you add `1`. You need to _count_ how often `'the'` is in Text - and add that counted amount - not `1` .

Comment: [python-finding-word-frequencies-of-list-of-words-in-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921436/python-finding-word-frequencies-of-list-of-words-in-text-file) - this handles the more complex case of finding word counts of a list of words but you can simplfy the given answers to fit your need

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to collect ALL words from ALL pages into a list.
Once you have the list of words you can use Counter that will give you the words and their number in the pdf

Example:

```
from collections import Counter

pdf_words = ['the','fox','the','jack']

counter = Counter(pdf_words)
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'the': 2, 'fox': 1, 'jack': 1})
```